# IllegalAccessError Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

In my app I check that the user has Google Play Services. But now I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(GooglePlayServicesUtil.java)
```

I use in my app the google play services 8.3.0, until yesterday I didn't got this error.

Comment: I did it, but it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because GooglePlayServicesUtil's isGooglePlayServicesAvailable method is deprecated now (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)).

You should check out and use the new one in the GoogleApiAvailability class (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)).

Comment: Thanks! I found that if the version of the Google Play Services is 8.7.03 (2645110-036) I got this error. Any other version (I tried ...-034 and ...-238) is okay.